# Can the default White Background of IE be changed?

Tags: internet-explorer

So I run a web application that is used in a dark room setting. The color scheme of the web page is dark. But when launching IE, before IE navigates to this page, IE is white, thus is pretty annoying in a dark setting.

Is there any way I can change the default background color of IE from white such that when we launch Internet Explorer there isn't a FLASH of white before the screen changes color to my site?

Going to tools and changing the background color only keeps the page black all the time (even when blank) when loading a new tab. If i completely load a new instance of IE, it still shows white at first.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of “launching” Internet Explorer, create a link to your app,
put it on your desktop, and double-click *it* to start IE. 
(Or put it into your “Start Menu” …)

Or create an HTML file that has no content but a very dark background,
and use that to fire up IE.